# Laravel Guest Middleware and user authentication

Tags: laravel

I just created a simple login with guest middleware that allows the user to access one account at a time, but I am just worried if this is the right way to do it.

```
/** Routes **/        
Route::group(['middleware' => 'guest'], function () {

        Route::get('/', 'LoginController@index')->name('login');
        Route::post('/', 'LoginController@post')->name('login.post');

    });



/** login.post controller **/
    public function post(Request $request){
            $this->rules($request);

            $rules = array(
                'username' => $request->username,
                'password' => $request->password,
            );

            if(Auth::attempt($rules)) {
                if(Auth::user()->is_active == true){
                /** IF THE USER IS CURRECTLY LOGIN **/
                 if(Auth::user()->is_login == true){
                   Auth::logout();
                   Session::flash('multilog', 'Your account is log-in to another device!!');
                   return redirect('/')->withInput();
                 }
                $user = user::find(Auth::user()->id); 
                $user->is_login = true;
                $user->save();
                return redirect('admin/home');
                }
                Session::flash('unactivated', 'Your account is not activated!!');
                return redirect('/')->withInput();
            }
            Session::flash('unmatch', 'Invalid username or password!!');  
            return redirect('/')->withInput();
        }
```

/**  **/

Answer (score 2):

If you are not sure, you can use Laravel to create authentication. Write in command line:

```
php artisan make:auth
```

Then just look how the logic works in files.
More you can read here:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/authentication